# Web information

Tags: transformer, datasheet, internet

I have three big boxes of transformers. I found some that go to computers, some games and toys.  A lot belong to tools, mostly drill/driver and of those the most are Drill Master drills and Sears. Is there anywhere on the internet,l I could put a model number in and find out what it goes to?

Comment: Have you tried using the google machine?

Comment: Most of the time, the model number is a part number assigned by the manufacturer of the device not the transformer manufacturer.  You really need to test each transformer with an AC voltmeter and a low voltage AC source to get an approximation of the turns ratio. The current rating (which is related to the power rating) is more difficult to ascertain but can be estimated by comparing the wire gauge and transformer size to transformers with known ratings.

Comment: I think you are asking about AC adapters (whether wall or desktop versions) that may or may not contain transformers. Regardless, the best title you could come up with was "Web information?" Please consider editing your title to reflect what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

Often, you will not find anything in the internet. Sites like https://www.alldatasheet.com/ often give no or bad results. Even if you find your components in second hand / surplus shops, they often provide only very sparse information themselves. You might write an email to the manufacturer, but usually, especially if they are based in China, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Some devices use standard AC adapters that don't carry their brand or part numbers. Others have them fully customized. You can google for it from the markings, and don't forget to check that great garage sale eBay which is a fantastic resource. The safety agency numbers will seldom be useful because they'll merely lead you to the adapter manufacturer, who is *very* seldom the manufacturer of the end product.

In the future, I recommend using an inexpensive label machine to label each and every AC adapter that darkens your door.

It can help in case the proper AC adapters get separated from their intended product, but also allows you to decide to confidently repurpose (which is on-topic here!) or dispose of adapters that are no longer required.